# why does eof() not work as I expect?

Tags: c++, eof

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    ifstream in("input.txt");
    int i = 0,sum=0;
    char x;
    while (!in.eof()){
        in >> i;
        if (in.good()) {
            cout << "integer is " << i << endl; sum += i; 
        }
        if (in.fail()) {
            in.clear();
            in >> x;
            cout << "the char is " << x << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << sum;
    char z;
    cin >> z;
}
```

and my input.txt is like:

bear: sdf 23 okI am fine 11q , 45

and  my screen output is like:

[the last number 45 doesn't show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4g45G.png)

So what happened here? why 45 is regarded as one out of file. And if I add a 's' immediately right next to 45, the screen will have two s showing up, rather than just one.

Comment: #inlcude -> #include

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when extracting symbols for 45,it tries to extract symbol after '5' (to check if number continues further) and sees end of file, setting `eofbit`. This makes `in.good()` test to fail. Suggestions:

```
while (!in.eof()){
    in >> i;
    if ( in ) { //Not .good(), just conversion to bool
```

Or

```
while (!in.eof()){
    if ( in >> i; ) { //both extraction and checking in same operation
```

Remember, `.good()` is not the same as checking stream state. `.good()` is telling if stream ready for **further** input. Bool conversion does `! .fail()` and checks if **last** operation was executed succesfully

Comment: So, when the last time "in" reads 45, it's set by "`std::ios::eof()`". At this moment, .`good()` fails, while `! .fail()` still return true.

Comment: @JiehongJiang Yes. Do not use `good()` to check success of previous operation. Both `good` and `eof` have very limited use and you should think twice before using them. In your case, usage of `eof` is one of those rare cases, but using `while (in.good()){` instead of `while (!in.eof()){` would be even better, as it captures critical stream failures (badbit) too.

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Well, "`eof()`" *does* work as expected, at least, how I expect it to work: it gets set when the stream somehow touches the end of file. If your file's last line actually ends with `'5'` rather than a newline, reading an integer stops due to touching newline and `std::ios_base::eofbit` gets set. Since `std::ios::good()` returns `false` if any bit is set, include `std::ios_base::failbit` the last value wouldn't be printed.

In general, `eof()` is more often misused than appropriately used. Essentially the only reasonable uses of `eof()` is to verify if the entire stream was consumed or to suppress an error message if `eof()` is set as it is expected that input fails at the end of the stream. Likewise, there is generally little use for `std::ios::good()`.